# heapdump of nodejs app - directly, without chrome inspect?

Tags: node.js, docker, node-inspector

I would like to inspect a nodejs application because I am pretty sure we have a memory leak there. Unfortunately the app is inside a docker container which is on behind a load balancer and secured by some security rules inside EC2.

I have full access to the server on which the container is running, but I would like to get a heapdump without opening the debug ports, that's a bit beyond my wage and responsibility. What I already did is running the node using the `--inspect` command.

Is there a way to get a heapdump directly from within the server without connecting via chrome to it?

Unfortunately `--heapsnapshot-signal` seems not to work since we are using Node 8.16.1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that successfully within the app itself with the help of [v8.getHeapSnapshot()](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8getheapsnapshotoptions). Periodically, it checks for [available free heap size](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8getheapstatistics) using `setInterval()` and triggers the creation of the snapshot once an arbitrary threshold is hit (25% in my case).